# Fecha actual en input html

Tags: php, html

Busco que el campo:

```
<input type="date" id="fecha" name="fecha"
```

De tipo *date* muestre la fecha actual del sistema, gracias.

Comment: Qué has intentado?

Comment: Otra opción sin recurrir a código de servidor (php) podrías usar [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com). Una librería muy util para todo lo que es manejo de fechas, fácil de usar.

Answer (score 5):

```
<input type="datetime" name="fecha"  value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d\TH-i");?>">
```

Podrias intentar con el codigo anterior mi estimado.

Answer (score 0):

hola por si no estas trabajando con un servidor local tambien lo puedes hacer con js con este codigo:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var now = new Date();

    var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);

    var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day) ;
    $("#fecha").val(today);
});
</script>
```

saludos

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas, todas las tomaré en cuenta

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar con este código, usando la función [**`date`**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php) de php

```
<input type="date" 
       id="txtfecha" 
       name="txtfecha" 
       class="form-control" 
       value="<?php echo date("Y-n-j"); ?>" 
       required/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya paso mucho pero bueno.

```
<?php $fcha = date("Y-m-d");?>

<input type="date" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo $fcha;?>" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas que te salga la fecha actual, deberas colocar la propiedad **date()** propio de php, dentro podras colocar que deseas obtener, como el date se basa en año-mes-dia lo podremos de la siguinte form:

```
date("y-m-d")
```

En el que y sera **year** mes sera **month** y la d **day**, todo eso en el inputo nos quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
<input type="date" id="fecha" name="fecha"  value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>">
```